# using getters and setters when having a same predefined property name

Tags: javascript

I was reading the MDN documentation of the [JavaScript getters](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), it's written there the following: (see the bolder text)

> It must not appear in an object literal with another get or with a
> data entry for the same property ({ get x() { }, get x() { } } **and {
> x: ..., get x() { } } are forbidden).**

after reading this I've tried to break this "forbidden" rule by this example with the use of the strict mode:

```js
'use strict';
const obj = {
  name: "Ahmad",
  get name() {
    return "override";
  }
}

console.log(obj.name);
```

as you can see saying it's "forbidden" doesn't mean that it's not going to work.

what does the MDN mean with "forbidden"?

and why it is forbidden? isn't it possible to overwrite object properties?

Please note that the same question applies to the setters, they have mentioned the same rule [there](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between ES specifications and browser implementations.

In this case, the [ES specifications](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-PropertySetParameterList) don't say how to treat the cases where the property name and the getter function name are the same. Since the behavior is unpredictable, MDN tells you it's forbidden.

There is a reason why that shouldn't ever be done, most of the case you can trigger a recursion by mistake, for example in this case:

```js
'use strict';
const obj = {
  name: "Ahmad",
  get name() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

console.log(obj.name);
```

If you want to overwrite an object property, re-assigning it is enough:

```
obj.name = 'override';
```

If you want more control over overwriting (for example assign a setter to an object), you can use [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Answer (score 1):

in addition to @Cristian Traìna this could return garbage value or browser heap memory could get exceded, thats why its forbidden.

```js
'use strict';
    const obj = {
        name: "Ahmad",
        get name(){
            return this.name;
        },
         get name(){
            return name;
        }
    }
    
    console.log(obj.name);
```